# How does this while loop even work

Tags: javascript, html, quicksort

```
function partition(num,begin,end){

    var pivot= num[begin];

    var beginning = begin-1 ;

    var ending = end+1 ;

    // over here the while loop says that the argument is true but,   
    // what is true, and how does this thing work  

    while (true) {

       beginning++;

        while ( beginning< end && num[beginning] < pivot)

            beginning++;

        ending--;

        while (ending>begin && num[ending] > pivot)

            ending--;

        if (beginning < ending)

            swap(num, beginning, ending);
        else

            return ending;
    }
function swap(num, begin, end) {

    var temp = num[begin];

    num[begin] = num[end];

    num[end] = temp;
}
```

the while loop in the function partition, it works but i would like to know how it works and how efficient is the code, thank you

Comment: "What is true" it means true

Comment: True like in 'not false'.

Comment: "What is true" - You need the philosophy site.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `while` loop, the bit you put in the parentheses is an *expression* to be *evaluated*. When you enter the loop, the program checks if the expression in the parentheses evaluates to `true`. If it is, your program enters the loop and runs until it gets to the end of the loop.

This can be interrupted by a few statements like `break` or `return`, as you see here. This loop is meant to execute continuously until it reaches the `return`.

Examples of expressions that evaluate to `true`:

`1+1 == 2`

`x < 100`, where `x` is 60

`true`, which is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

A while-loop will run as long as the condition is true.
while(true) will run 'forever' if not ended inside (break; return; etc), cause its always true. As while(false) would not run even once.

Answer (score 0):

while (result of an evaluated condition) {

}

while runs if whatever between the ( ) evaluates to true.
so, if you type while(true) , then its is true.
if you type while (1+1==2), then is true, and is same as written above
if you type while( 1+1 != 4) then thats also true, because we are saying its true, if its not = for etc.